# How to schedule python script in a folder using crontab

Tags: bash, python, cron

I have some python scripts saved in a sub-folder called `"Documents/downloadFundamentals"`

And I have the following bash script:

```
/home/john/.virtualenvs/investFundamentals/bin/python scrapStockList.py
/home/john/.virtualenvs/investFundamentals/bin/python downloadHistoricalData.py
/home/john/.virtualenvs/investFundamentals/bin/python updateHistoricalData.py
/home/john/.virtualenvs/investFundamentals/bin/python insertDocsToCollection.py
/home/john/.virtualenvs/investFundamentals/bin/python filterStocks.py
/home/john/.virtualenvs/investFundamentals/bin/python getCurrentPortfolio.py
/home/john/.virtualenvs/investFundamentals/bin/python accountSummary.py
```

The crontab task seems to be running, but no output.

Do I need to add the directory before each.py?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - yes, you have to make it either

```
/home/john/.virtualenvs/investFundamentals/bin/python /path/to/script/scrapStockList.py
```

or use  `#!/usr/bin/env python` and make each file executable with `chmod +x /path/to/scrapStockList.py`. Use of `virtualenv` suggests you may be running Python version other than system default, so probably first option is more suitable for your case.

To quote [related post by Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38956/85039):

> Cron's default path is implementation-dependent, so check your man page

When you call `python script.py`, the interpreter looks for `script.py` in current working directory. So your commands fail because Python interpreter in your question starts out in the working directory which is other than where your scripts are located.