# How to schedule a cronjob for python script to be executed on weekdays?

Tags: 18.04, cron, python3

I need to set up cron job for python script scheduled at 08:00 15:00 and 18:00 IST

My python location is

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

and script location is

```
~/Documents/Python/script.py
```

I have tried the following solutions:

1. [How to schedule python script in a folder using crontab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106531/how-to-schedule-python-script-in-a-folder-using-crontab)
2. [Schedule python script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048358/schedule-python-script)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727935/execute-python-script-via-crontab/8728014

but not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information is not as easy to find as usual, but the full documention can be viewed by doing:

```
man 5 crontab
```

which reveals this:

```
          field          allowed values
          -----          --------------
          minute         0-59
          hour           0-23
          day of month   1-31
          month          1-12 (or names, see below)
          day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
```

There is also a reminder of these fields at the top of every new crontab, but you may have deleted that:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
```

So, in order to run your script at 8:00, 15:00 and 18:00 on weekdays, do

```
0 8,15,18 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/python3 /home/[username]/Documents/Python/script.py
```

where `1-5` means Monday through Friday.

You need to fill in your own username, as `cron` does not understand the `~`shortcut.

Comment: Cron job not executing,                                                                                                        I have changed the timing for trial:`0 8,15,19 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/python  /home/[username]/Documents/Python/script.py`

Comment: Look in /var/log/syslog to see why the cron job didn't run.